# How to estimate a Logistic Regression function in a quadratic form?

Tags: logistic

I am trying to use a mixed-integer programming solver to optimize the following logistic regression function:

$$\mathop {\min }\limits_w {{\exp ({w^T}x + b)} \over {1 + \exp ({w^T}x + b)}}$$

There is no solver (that I know of) can represent this function to optimize the logistic regression. I am thinking if I could represent the logistic regression with a quadratic function so I can input it to the mixed-integer quadratic solver.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to minimize $\hat y$? Are you sure that's right? As far as I'm aware, that's pretty different from maximizing the log-likelihood.

Comment: Why do you want5 an integer solution? There is a lot of detail you didnt tell us!

Comment: I'm sorry for being not very clear. I was supposed to use the logistic regression formula as a classifier by using the log-sum-exp function. I have found a paper that answers my question. http://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/matlab/rgp/battlse.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logistic function

$$\frac {e^z}  {1 + e^z} = \frac {1}  {1 + e^{-z}}$$

has  infimum $0$ for $z\rightarrow -\infty$. So if your vector $w$ is not constrained to be finite, you will find that at least one of its elements will tend to $-\infty$ in the attempt to minimize the expression.

Answer (score 0):

For a two-class problem, we can use the formulation provided by finding the best piece-wise linear convex approximation of the two-term log-sum-exp function.

http://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/matlab/rgp/battlse.pdf